# Get the Record from Update Column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I want to ask about SQL Server. I have some column `Point`. With every purchase of something, this `point` value will increase.

For example: the first serial account 100 has purchased MILK, then `Point` goes from 50 to 75.

The problem is, can I get the record from update `Point` column if first 50 become to 75 with trigger then will write to new column, like PointLog?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad English..

Comment: If my idea about what you're trying to do is right, then you have some kind of bonus system customers can get points for every purchase and later cash them in (or get some other stuff for it). Then yes, you could use a trigger here to update the bonus points of a customer. But most likely the points can also be calculated from the stored purchases which is the safer bet I guess. Please add your tables' structure and meaning so we can understand this better.

Comment: next problem is, how i can get the records from update ?, ok wait, i will screenshot some table

Comment: @novatria, add the `CREATE TABLE` and trigger code to you question as text rather than as an image.

Comment: if is it controlled by a stored procedure, then why you don't add it within that procedure rather than a trigger ? my point is, you need to keep your code intact so it'll be easier for you or anyone to follow and expand or modify without an issue.

Comment: im so sorry, i have fix it for get the record with Trigger AFTER UPDATE FROM DELETED